# Which commutative groups are the group of units of some field?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, gr.group-theory

Inspired by [a recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12873/split-powers-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field) on the multiplicative group of fields.  Necessary conditions include that there are at most $n$ solutions to $x^n = 1$ in such a group and that any finite subgroup is cyclic.  Is this sufficient?  (Edit:  Well, no, it's not, since the only such groups which are finite are the cyclic groups of order one less than a prime power.  Hmm.)

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, the finite case is known, so your question is about the infinite case, right?

Comment: Perhaps not what you're looking for (and I do not really know their contents) but the following look interesting: http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/pdf_extract/s2-1/1/369 and http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/0025-5726/35/2/A05

Comment: In the case of number fields or function fields for instance, units would mean the units in the ring of integers.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone use "units" in that way.

Comment: A (closed) duplicate with further answers can be found here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204144/obstructions-for-a-group-to-be-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following paper claims an answer to this question:

> Dicker, R. M.
> A set of independent axioms for a field and a condition for a group to be the multiplicative group of a field.
> Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 18 1968 114--124.

You can find it here:

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Dicker1966.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Dicker1966.pdf)

One might hope for a more aesthetically appealing characterization.  I don't know if such a thing has ever been given.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe I should have just asked for nice necessary conditions...

Comment: @qiaochu: I wonder why you are satisfied with this answer, because I already mentioned this paper in the other question which you refer to.

Comment: Oops; I don't seem to have read that question too closely.  Sorry!

Comment: Dear Pete: it seems that the link is broken. Do you still have the article? I would love to see it.

Answer (score 7):

Another characterization is theorem 2.1 in this paper on the field with one element:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.3537

If H is a commutative group, let H+ be H together with a new element 0.  To give a field structure on H+ is equivalent to giving a bijection s:H+ --> H+ that commutes with all of its conjugates-by-H.

Maybe this is similar to Dicker's characterization?  Dicker mentions the operation x --> 1-x, while the s in Connes-Consani is meant to be x --> x + 1.