# How should I think about delooping?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

When talking about the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G,n)$, we usually restrict our attention to the situation where $G$ is abelian.  In that case, we get $\Omega K(G,n)=K(G,n-1)$, so we can call $K(G,n)$ a *delooping* of $K(G,n-1)$.

Since $\pi_n$ is always abelian for $n>1$, it only makes sense to talk about $K(G,1)=BG$ for $G$ nonabelian anyways.  So there definitely shouldn't be delooping of this space, because then it would have $\pi_2=G$, which is impossible.  From the previous paragraph, it seems like we should therefore be able to say that the nonabelianity of $G$ (i.e., the nontriviality of the commutator $[G,G]$) is the obstruction to delooping $BG$.  But this isn't very satisfying, because I can't quite see what's going on with the actual space.

All of which motivates my (slightly open-ended/up-to-interpretation) question:

**How should I think about delooping?  Is it nothing more than thing like "for the space $X$ that we care about, it just so happens that we've got $Y$ with $\Omega Y\simeq X$", or is there a definite way to measure obstructions?  In the cases where a delooping exists, is there an explicit method for its construction?**

Comment: This is a bit vague.  There's machinery that detects when something is a loop space, I suggest you read up about that first and then ask a more focussed question when you've done that.

Comment: Start with J. P. May's "The geometry of iterated loop spaces", LNM 271, or Boardman-Vogt's "Homotopy invariant algebraic structures on topological spaces", LNM 347.  Roughly, the _structure_ of a nice multiplication operation on X provides you with a delooping.  Stasheff's joint review: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=420610

Comment: The answer to your motivation -- before your bold question -- is that $\pi_1$ of a loop space is always abelian.  There's a very cute argument for this, which is a standard intro algebraic-topology homework problem.  But your bolded question is different.  "Delooping" could be interpreted as the classifying space functor.  So one interpretation of your question could be, provided the classifying space functor is defined for $X$, when is $\Omega BX$ naturally equivalent to $X$?  Is that the kind of question you're interested in? 

Comment: @Andrew: I figured as much, I just didn't even know what the machinery is called.  Which is what (hopefully) distinguishes my question from a question like "Tell me about group theory."  I didn't expect someone to write me a textbook, of course.  Maybe the problem is also that I'm just looking for a nice picture I can keep in my head, which I would get from understanding this machinery.

Comment: @Ryan: That's just something like the Eckmann-Hilton argument, right?  Even without knowing that, my point was just that *a priori* it's impossible to shift the homotopy up a notch if $\pi_1$ is nonabelian.  I do like the perspective that I'm just looking for a functor $B$, but what do you mean "provided the classifying space functor is defined for $X$"?  As far as I know, a classifying space is just the representing space for $X$-bundles.  Are there pathological topological spaces where such a thing doesn't exist, or is it deeper than that?

Comment: I wasn't aware the result is named the Eckmann-Hilton argument, but yes, it's essentially that argument.   On your second point, classifying spaces make sense for a variety of objects, in particular for categories. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23857/what-does-the-classifying-space-of-a-category-classify So you could try to make sense of your question for quite a variety of $X$'s. 

Comment: "Classifying spaces": I'm just trying to clarify some language here. To a topological group $G$ is associated a space $BG$ which may be called a delooping of $G$ or a classifying space of $G$. It is called a delooping because $\Omega BG$ is (weakly homotopy) equivalent to the space $G$. It is called a classifying space because it is the base of the universal principal $G$-bundle (or you could think of some other type of bundle with structure group $G$, for example real oriented vector bundles of rank $n$ if $G=SO(n)$.

Comment: (continued) So people sometimes say "classifying space" for delooping, if it's not a group. Note that the following two conditions are equivalent: (1) $\Omega Y$ is equivalent to $X$. (2) There is a fibration with base $Y$, fiber $X$, and contractible total space.

Comment: Note that $\Omega Y$ has a multiplication which is not associative but is associative up to homotopy in a certain strong sense ("$A_\infty$"). It is a marvelous fact (pointed out by others here) that this has a converse: If $X$ has an $A_\infty$ multiplication (and if the resulting monoid $\pi_0(X)$ is a group), then $X$ can be delooped.

But sometimes you deloop a space by discovering a fibration having that space as fiber and having contractible total space.

Comment: Finally, may I point out that the same space can have essentially different deloopings. Two spaces may have homotopy equivalent loopspaces without being homotopy equivalent themselves. 

Comment: @ Tom, regarding your last point: This isn't an example since $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as spaces, but I'm pretty sure isn't $\Omega B \mathbb{N}$ also just the circle.  If so, perhaps we could construct an example where a topological monoid and its groupification already have distinct homotopy types (although off the top of my head, I can't think of any topological monoids that aren't already groups -- maybe it's impossible?).  And in any case, what do we want to mean when we're asking for a delooping, then?  Is there some sort of universal delooping?

Comment: Aaron, there are lots of cases where group-completion "destroys" the homotopy-type of the original monoid.  Consider the monoid $\\{0,1,2,\cdots,\infty\\}$ under addition.  It's group-completion is trivial.   You might like to read this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13942/computing-the-structure-of-the-group-completion-of-an-abelian-monoid-how-hard-ca

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  So there's a funny topological monoid $M=\mathbb{N}\cup \{ \infty\}$, and it's valid to say that $\Omega BM=*$?

Comment: There are interesting deloopings for BG when G non abelian sometimes for example when G is $U(\infty)$. There is this H-space $BU^{\otimes}$ and BBU tensor comes up in twisted K-theory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible answer: Stasheff proved that a (connected) space $X$ is (homotopy equivalent to) a loopspace if and only if $X$ is an algebra over the $A_\infty$ operad (or rather I should say *an* $A_\infty$ operad).

See for instance [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf).

Comment: That's not exactly right as stated -- to be a loop space X has to not only be an algebra over an $A_\infty$ operad, but must also be *grouplike*, i.e. $\pi_0$ of it is a group (under the monoid operation induced by the $A_\infty$ structure).  Otherwise $\Omega B X$ is only a "group completion" of X.

Comment: (The linked article simplifies the situation by mentioning only *connected* spaces, which are of course automatically grouplike.)

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure whether you'll like this, but my natural response to "how should I think about delooping?" is to invoke (higher) category theory.  You may know that a homotopy 1-type, i.e. a space (probably a CW complex) with $\pi_n=0$ for n>1, is uniquely specified up to (weak) homotopy equivalence by its fundamental groupoid.  In fact, one has an equivalence of (2- or homotopy-) categories, so we can identify homotopy 1-types with groupoids.  Under this identification, the space BG which deloops a discrete group G is identified with the groupoid with one object and G as the automorphism group of that object.  So one-step delooping of a discrete group really *is* just the simple process of considering a group as a one-object groupoid (although in the homotopy theory world it requires a fairly elaborate construction).

At higher levels, the "homotopy hypothesis" in higher category theory (which is a theorem for some definitions of higher category) says that homotopy n-types can be identified with n-groupoids, and arbitrary homotopy types with ∞-groupoids.  Moreover, the identification of groups with one-object groupoids is believed to continue to higher categories as well: 2-groups (i.e. groupoids equipped with an extra group structure up to coherent isomorphism) can be identified with one-object 2-groupoids, and similarly an n-group can be identified with a one-object n-groupoid.  Thus, deloopability of a space requires that it be equipped with a suitable group structure (up to homotopy, i.e. up to equivalence), and in that case its delooping corresponds on the categorical side to regarding an n-group as a one-object n-groupoid (where possibly n=∞).

Finally, as to the obstruction to delooping BG when G is not abelian, only when G is abelian is BG itself a (2-)group.  The reason is the same one that other people have mentioned—Eckmann-Hilton—but I prefer to think about it in these terms.

Comment: I do like this.  In my imaginary autobiography, this chapter of my life will be entitled "How I learned to stop worrying and love category theory".  Why doesn't the identification with groupoids extend to an equivalence involving non-simply-connected spaces, though?  This seems like it's probably answered in your second paragraph, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It does.  In fact, only a non-simply-connected space can be modeled by a non-discrete groupoid, since the automorphism groups of the groupoid specify the $\pi_1$s of the space.

Comment: For a group $G$ to be delooped 3 times or above (and pertains the higher groupoid structures), what extra structure should it have?

Comment: @Student An ordinary 1-group $G$ can be delooped infinitely many times as soon as it is abelian.  For an $n$-group or $\infty$-group, there is a hierarchy of "more and more commutativity": an $E_n$-group can be delooped $n$ times.