# ${\rm II}_1$-factors with finite commutant and trivial intersection generate $B(H)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $H$ be an $\infty$-dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.
Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B} \subset B(H)$ be ${\rm II}_1$-factors such that $\mathcal{A}'$, $\mathcal{B}'$ are also ${\rm II}_1$-factors and  $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{C}$.

*Examples*:
(1) Take $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}'$ then $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{C}$ by definition of a factor.
(2) Take $(\mathcal{A}' \subset \mathcal{B})$ an irreducible subfactor, then $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{C}$ by definition of irreducibility.

Obviously $\langle \mathcal{A}' , \mathcal{B}' \rangle = \mathbb{C}' = B(H)$, with the *notation* $\langle S \rangle := (S \cup S^* \cup \mathbb{C})  ''$.

**Question**: Is it also true that $\langle \mathcal{A} , \mathcal{B} \rangle = B(H)$, or equivalently, that $\mathcal{A'} \cap \mathcal{B'} = \mathbb{C}$ ?
Else, what are counterexamples?

*Remark*: It's true for the examples (1) and (2).

Comment: @ougao: I don't understand where you use $N$ for building $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, perhaps there is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is trivially false. Start with $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \subset B(H)$ that are not a counterexample and define $$\mathcal{A}^{(2)} = \{A \oplus A \in B(H \oplus H): A \in \mathcal{A}\}$$ and $$\mathcal{B}^{(2)} = \{B \oplus B \in B(H \oplus H): B \in \mathcal{B}\}.$$ They and their commutants are still $II_1$ factors and their intersection is still trivial, but their commutants $M_2(\mathcal{A}')$ and $M_2(\mathcal{B}')$ now intersect in the scalar matrices. *The answer is now in its true, correct, and final form. I will notify the Cyber Police of any additional unauthorized edits.*

Comment: I rolled back Sebastien's edit, which seemed to change completely the meaning of what Nik Weaver wrote

Comment: hey, I got the check mark, that's all that matters

Comment: However I agree with part of Sebastien's edit, namely that you probably mean M2 of A', etc

Comment: @YemonChoi: Is it fashion to keep an answer with obvious typos?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux you changed "now intersect" to "don't intersect". That is not fixing a typo.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux moreover, I feel it is more courteous to ASK someone who answers your question if they have made minor errors or typos.

Comment: @YemonChoi: OK thank you, the next time, I will ask. Now,  $M_2(\mathcal{A}') \cap M_2(\mathcal{B}') \neq \mathbb{C}$, i.e. they "don't intersect" in the scalar.

Comment: @NikWeaver: Is it also *trivially false* if we enlarge the question,  replacing "$\mathcal{A}' \cap \mathcal{B}' = \mathbb{C}$" by "$\mathcal{A}' \cap \mathcal{B}'$ finite dimensional" ? In your example,  $\mathcal{A^{(2)}}' \cap \mathcal{B^{(2)}}'  \simeq M_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is finite dimensional.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: I think the same idea works though. In my example we go to $\mathcal{A} \otimes I_2$ and $\mathcal{B}\otimes I_2$ which have commutants $\mathcal{A}' \otimes M_2$ and $\mathcal{B}$

Comment: @NikWeaver: yes precisely, for having an infinite dimensional intersection by modifying your example, we need to go to $\mathcal{A} \otimes I_{\infty}$ which have commutant $\mathcal{A}' \otimes B(H)$, which is not ${\rm II}_1$ but ${\rm II}_{\infty}$.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter before I was finished ... I was saying, now replace with $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{N}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are $II_1$ factors with trivial intersection whose commutants have nontrivial intersection.

Comment: @NikWeaver: yes but this nontrivial intersection could be also finite dimensional, else $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ themselves answer the generalized question, but do they exist?

Comment: Oh you're right, I take it back.

Comment: @NikWeaver: if you've no objection, I will open a new post for this generalized question.

Comment: Honestly? I think you should spend a couple of days working on it yourself before opening a new post. Otherwise it feels like you are abusing the community's goodwill to have people do your thinking for you. Just my opinion.

Comment: It seems there are counterexamples for the generalized question by using $(\mathcal{A} \otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}$ and $(\mathcal{B}\otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}$. So we need to generalize more the question by replacing "finite dimensional" by "hyperfinite".

Comment: [Infinite tensor product of states](http://mathoverflow.net/q/161169/34538) and [your answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/161209/34538).

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: if you've answered the infinite dimensional question, perhaps you could say so in an edit to your original post, to give the answer some visibility.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I've posted it as an answer (perhaps a better place than in the original post).

Answer (score 1):

Transformation of the answer of Nik, for an **hyperfinite** infinite dimensional intersection:

He gave the counterexample  $(\mathcal{A} \otimes I_2)' \cap (\mathcal{B} \otimes I_2)' \simeq M_2(\mathbb{C})$, for $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A'}$, $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{B'}$ ${\rm II}_1$-factors and $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A'} \cap \mathcal{B'} = \mathbb{C}$.
Let two states on  $(\mathcal{A} \otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}$ and $(\mathcal{B} \otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}$ generating ${\rm II}_1$-factors $\mathcal{M}=\overline{(\mathcal{A} \otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}}$ and $\mathcal{N}=\overline{(\mathcal{B} \otimes I_2)^{\otimes \infty}}$ such that $\mathcal{M'}=\overline{(\mathcal{A'} \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C}))^{\otimes \infty}}$ and $\mathcal{N'}=\overline{(\mathcal{B'} \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C}))^{\otimes \infty}}$ are ${\rm II}_1$ factors, $\mathcal{M} \cap \mathcal{N} = \mathbb{C} $  and $\mathcal{M'} \cap \mathcal{N'} \simeq \overline{M_2(\mathbb{C})^{\otimes \infty}} \simeq \mathcal{R}$ the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$-factor.
For more details about infinite tensor product of von Neumann algebras, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161209/34538) of Nik.

**Generalized question** (posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177686/34538)):
  Let $\mathcal{A}_1 \dots \mathcal{A}_n \subset B(H)$ be ${\rm II}_1$-factors such that   $\forall i \, \,  \mathcal{A}_i'$ is also a ${\rm II}_1$-factor and  $\bigcap_i \mathcal{A}_i = \mathbb{C}$.
 Is it true that $\bigcap_i \mathcal{A}'_i$ is *hyperfinite*? Else, what are counterexamples?

Comment: Seems like some justification is needed, but I think this works.