# ${\rm II}_1$-factors with finite commutant: $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow \mathcal{A}' \cap \mathcal{B}'$ hyperfinite?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, amenability

Let $\mathcal{A} , \mathcal{B} \subset B(H)$ be ${\rm II}_1$-factors such that   $\mathcal{A}', \mathcal{B}' $ are also a ${\rm II}_1$-factors.

**Question**:   $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{C} \, \,   \Rightarrow \, \, \mathcal{A}' \cap \mathcal{B}' $  [hyperfinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Amenable_von_Neumann_algebras)?
 Else, what are counterexamples?     (see examples in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177597/34538) *and* its answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are both finite index subfactors of a nonamenable ${\rm II}_1$ factor $M \subset \mathcal B(L^2M)$ such that $N_1 \cap N_2 = \mathbb C$, then $N_1'$ and $N_2'$ are both finite and $N_1' \cap N_2'$ is nonamenable since it contains $M'$.

For an example of such a situation consider non-trivial finite groups $G$ and $H$, set $\Gamma = G * H$, and $M = *_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \mathbb M_2(\mathbb C)$. Then the action of $\Gamma$ on itself by left multiplication induces a properly outer action on $M$ and we can set $N_1 = M^G$ and $N_2 = M^H$, so that $N_1 \cap N_2 = M^\Gamma = \mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9211013v1.pdf) of Ken Dykema, $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb C)^{\star n} \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{3n/4})$ for $n>1$, and $M \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{\infty})$, isn't it?

Comment: There is something unclear for me: let $G$ be a non-trivial finite group and $N = *_{\gamma \in G} \mathbb M_2(\mathbb C)$, then $N \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_s)$, $N^G = \mathbb{C}$ but $N^G$ is finite index in $N$. Where is the error?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: Yes, $M \cong L(\mathbb F_\infty)$. The reason that $M^\Gamma = \mathbb C$ is not because the action of $\Gamma$ on itself is transitive, but rather because the action has no finite orbits.

Comment: I see, thank you! But then, what's the difference with $\bigotimes_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \mathbb M_2(\mathbb C)$ generating the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$-factor $\mathcal R$, what's about $\mathcal R^Γ$?

Comment: The situation is similar, for the shift action $\mathcal R^\Gamma = \mathbb C$ if and only if $| \Gamma | = \infty$.

Comment: But if $\Gamma$ is amenable, then it acts outerly on $\mathcal{R}$ with only one manner. So either this shift action above is not outer, or the subfactor $(\mathcal{R}^{\Gamma} \subset \mathcal{R})$ does not encodes $\Gamma$ if it is infinite, what about?

Comment: $(\mathcal R^\Gamma \subset \mathcal R)$ does not encode $\Gamma$ if it is infinite.

Comment: What is happening if the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$-factor $\mathcal{R}$ is replaced by  the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_{\infty}$-factor $\mathcal{R}_{\infty}$?

Comment: It's similar, $(\mathcal R_\infty^\Gamma \subset \mathcal R_\infty)$ does not encode $\Gamma$ either.

Comment: Is there a von Neumann algebra $M$ such that for all (countable) discrete group $\Gamma$, $(M^{\Gamma} \subset M)$ encodes $\Gamma$?  (restriction to finitely presented groups if necessary).

Comment: I'm not sure how to make your question precise, could you explain more what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok: Is there a von Neumann algebra $M$ such that every locally compact second countable group $G_1$ and $G_2$ acting outerly and faithfully on it and  $(M^{G_1} ⊂ M) ≃ (M^{G_2} ⊂ M )$ implies that $G_1≃G_2$?

Comment: The answer to that question is yes, since there exist von Neumann algebras (even II$_1$ factors) which have no non-trivial outer automorphisms. Do you want to assume that certain groups have properly outer faithful actions? If so do you want some uniqueness properties? Then I'm guessing that the answer will be no.

Comment: In fact I was thinking "act outerly" instead of "acting outerly" in the last comment.