# Is certain topology-related set a distributive lattice?

Tags: set-theory, lattices, filters

In [my research](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) the following problem appeared (and if it is true, this solves positively several my conjectures):

Let $U$ be a fixed set (usually $U$ is infinite). Let $n$ be a fixed index set ($n$ may be infinite).

I call a *staroid* such an $n$-ary relation $f$ between sets (which are subsets of some fixed set $U$) such that:

1. $X\notin f$ if any component $X_i$ of $X$ is empty set.
2. $\{(k,I\cup J)\} \cup L\in f\Leftrightarrow \{(k,I)\} \cup L\in f \vee \{(k,J)\} \cup L\in f$ for every index $k\in n$, sets $I,J\in\mathscr{P}U$ and an indexed family $L$ of subsets of $U$ such that $\operatorname{dom} L=n\setminus\{k\}$.
3. If $X\in f$ and $\forall i\in n:Y_i\supseteq X_i$ then $Y\in f$ for every $n$-indexed family $Y$ of subsets of $U$.

Note that first two axioms can be reformulated as:

- The set $\{ X\in U \mid L\cup\{(k,X)\}\in f \}$ is a [free star](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/dual-filters.pdf) for every $L\in U^{n\setminus\{k\}}$ for every $k\in n$.

As I've shown in [this online note](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/dual-filters.pdf) free stars are isomorphic to ideals and filters.

Conjecture: The poset of staroids (ordered by set-theoretic inclusion) is a distributive lattice. I would like to prove that it is also a co-brouwerian lattice and a co-frame.

The same question without the third axiom is also interesting.

I have only one idea to solve this: Consider functions $L$ and $L'$ equivalent iff they differ in a finite number of arguments. Then somehow use the generated equivalency relation. But I have no idea how to go further in solution of this problem.

Note that for $n=\{0,1\}$ this conjecture is true. See [this my online draft](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/funcoids-are-frame.pdf) and [a more categorical proof](http://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/topogeny) ($2$-staroids are easily identified with [funcoids](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) or [topogenies](http://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/topogeny)).

Answer (score 3):

What follows uses finiteness of $n$ but I think it works for infinite $n$ too.

First let us note that for finite $n$ the third axiom follows from the first two (because for finite $n$ the third axiom follows from its particular case when $Y_j=X_j$ for all $j$ except one).

So staroids are subsets $f$ of $(\mathscr PU)^n$ whose characteristic functions $(\mathscr PU)^n\to2$ are $\textit{multi-join-homomorphisms}$.

A multi-join-homomorphism $m:\prod_{i\in n}S_i\to S$, where $S_i$ and $S$ are join-semilattices, is a map which is a join-semilattice homomorphism in each argument separately.

It is well known that multi-join-homomorphisms are (at least for finite $n$) representable by the $\textit{tensor product}$ of semilattices. That is, for any join-semilattices $(S_i)_{i\in n}$ there is a join-semilattice $\bigotimes_{i\in n}S_i$ receiving a multi-join-homomorphism $\otimes:\prod_{i\in n}S_i\to\bigotimes_{i\in n}S_i$ which is universal, i. e. for any other multi-join-homomorphism $m:\prod_{i\in n}S_i\to S$ there is a unique (ordinary) join-homomorphism $m_\otimes:\bigotimes_{i\in n}S_i\to S$ with $m=m_\otimes\circ\otimes$.

It follows that staroids may be identified with join-homomorphisms $(\mathscr PU)^{\otimes n}\to2$, which are in turn identifiable with (complements of) ideals of $(\mathscr PU)^{\otimes n}$.

PS

I believe that one may give a more explicit description of $\bigotimes_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i$ as follows: there must be an isomorphism $\bigotimes_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i\cong\mathscr P_{\vee\Pi}(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$, where $\mathscr P_{\vee\Pi}(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$ is the sub-join-semilattice of $\mathscr P(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$ generated by the parallelepipeds $\prod_{i\in n}X_i$. Namely, the multi-join-homomorphism $\Pi:\prod_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i\to\mathscr P_{\vee\Pi}(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$ sending $X\in\prod_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i$ to $\prod_{i\in n}X_i$ seems to be universal: for a multi-join-homomorphism $m:\prod_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i\to S$ a join-homomorphism $m_\Pi:\mathscr P_{\vee\Pi}(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)\to S$ with $m=m_\Pi\circ\Pi$ is uniquely determined by $m_\Pi(\prod_{i\in n}X_i)=m(X)$. It just remains to find out whether this $m_\Pi$ is correctly defined, i. e. whether there are "extra" relations between joins of parallelepipeds in $\mathscr P(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$...

PPS

Note also that there is a map from $\mathscr P(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$ to ideals of $\mathscr P_{\vee\Pi}(\prod_{i\in n}U_i)$ sending a subset of $\prod_{i\in n}U_i$ to the set of all finite joins of parallelepipeds contained in it. Thus ideals of $\mathscr P(U^n)$ correspond to (possibly all) staroids.

Realized later:

In fact coproducts of distributive lattices are given by the tensor product, so under Stone/Priestley duality they correspond to cartesian products of spectral/Priestley spaces. Thus $(\mathscr PU)^{\otimes n}$ is the $n$-th copower of $\mathscr PU$ in the category of distributive lattices, hence its dual is the $n$-th power of the dual of $\mathscr PU$, i. e. of $\beta U$. Thus staroids correspond to open/closed sets of the Stone space $(\beta U)^n$.

Explicitly, to an open set $W$ of $\prod_{i\in n}\beta U_i$ corresponds the staroid
$$
\{\ (X_i)_{i\in n}\ |\ \exists (X_i\in\chi_i\in\beta U_i)_{i\in n}\textrm{ s. t. }(\chi_i)_{i\in n}\notin W\ \}
$$
whereas to a staroid $\Sigma\subseteq\prod_{i\in n}\mathscr PU_i$ corresponds the open set
$$
\{\ (\chi_i)_{i\in n}\in\prod_{i\in n}\beta U_i\ |\ \exists (X_i\in\chi_i)_{i\in n}\textrm{ s. t. }\ (X_i)_{i\in n}\notin\Sigma\ \}.
$$

This now works for infinite $n$ (and also for non-constant families $(U_i)_{i\in n}$).

Comment: A reference text (preferably cheap) about multi-join-homomorphism?

Comment: In the case $n=2$ staroids bijectively correspond to filters (or ideals) on the boolean lattice of **finite** unions of binary cartesian products on $U$. There is (again if $n=2$) a "natural" injection (which is not a surjection) from $2$-staroids to filters on $U^2$. See http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html - Let us relate this with your suppositions ("PS" and "PPS" which I haven't yet read carefully enough).

Comment: If you google for tensor product of (semi)lattices you will find several relevant texts. Just to give an example - probably the most relevant one I found is ["The Boolean Algebra of Cubical Areas as a Tensor Product in
the Category of Semilattices with Zero"](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Emmanuel.Haucourt/uploads/publication/ice2014.pdf)

Comment: As for your second comment - basically my PS and PPS say that the same things hold for any finite $n$.

Comment: Well more precisely PPS talks about a surjection from ideals of $\mathscr P(U^n)$ onto ideals of the semilattice of finite unions of parallelepipeds - just intersect the ideal with the subsemilattice.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot about the duality - I will add this to the answer in a minute

Comment: Are you sure that the "Realized later" holds for infinite $n$? If it is true, then staroids form a frame (and it is what I need).

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure (although one has to check it carefully). In fact one only needs the particular case of the duality - the classical one between Stone spaces and Boolean algebras. Tensor product (including infinite) is also coproduct in Boolean algebras, for the infinite case one has to take elements $\otimes_{i\in n}x_i$ with almost all of them equal to 1, just as for opens in the Tychonoff product.

Comment: One thing though - this way one only captures staroids with almost all $X_i$ equal to $U_i$ (I think).

Comment: I m still not convinced that staroids are a distributive lattice for infinite index set $n$. Does it follow from the duality which you have mentioned? I would probably not asked my question if I was interested only in the finite case (it seems I knew how to prove the infinite case even before I've asked my question; however I have not yet written the proof down). What do you say about almost all $x_i$ equal to $1$? The class of staroids with all $x_i$ equal to $1$ is very much too thin. Or do you say that almost all are equal to $1$ only in the definition of the product?

Comment: Where to get the proof that the tensor product for semilattices coincides with the coproduct of boolean lattices?

Comment: I don't understand what you say about infinite tensor products (of semilattices): It looks like that there are even no agreed by all definition of infinite tensor product. Or is there?

Comment: Thank you very much. But you haven't answered my comment asking how (in general and in particular for semilattices) is defined infinite tensor product

Comment: I also don't see (to complete the proof) why the category of Priestley spaces has products

Comment: "In fact coproducts of distributive lattices are given by the tensor product". I understand this as: "coproducts of distributive lattices are semilattice-tensor-product". Correct? I'd recommend you to express this more clearly in your answer.

Comment: Oh, well, it seems yet one fragment of the proof is missing: Are mult-join-homomorphism for infinite $n$ representable as join-semilattice tensor product? Do I miss something? Can you show a proof? I am not an expert in this topic

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think I follow what you're saying, but there might be a slight sticking point in accounting for Victor's axiom 3. I'm going to reformulate some of it in a separate answer; I'd be obliged if you'd have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while. @ToddTrimble gave an accurate account for the finite case. The infinite case only covers the poset of staroids with $X_i=U_i$ for almost all $i$, I will add details to my answer.

Comment: The poset of staroids with $X_i=U_i$ for almost all $i$ is of no interest (except if this special case can be used to prove that the poset of **all** staroids or prestaroids is a distributive lattice). Again: This special case by itself is of no interest.

Comment: @porton Yes, I understand. Unfortunately right now I do not have possibility to concentrate on this, hopefully I'll be able to do it tomorrow.

Comment: @porton Sorry, still could not find enough time to think about it properly. One consideration though: I suspect that what will capture at least more staroids could be open sets of $\beta(\prod(U_i))$, with $\prod(U_i)$ equipped with the product topology (of discrete spaces), as opposed to $\prod(\beta(U_i))$ - at least the former has more open sets compared to the latter...

Comment: On your last comment:
I have proved that the thing which I call "small identify staroid" in general is not representable as join (or meet dependently on your duality) of product of ultrafilters. See my book

Comment: I just realized (pretty belatedly) that the infinite tensor product that gives copowers of distributive lattices or Boolean algebras (a filtered colimit of finite tensor powers) is not the same as the universal recipient of join-multilinear maps $PU^n \to PU^{\otimes n}$. Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11767/infinite-tensor-products In fact infinite tensor products in the latter sense seem difficult to understand and work with.

Comment: @ToddTrimble correct; for the copower one has to take tensors which are 1 almost everywhere; in other words, the subalgebra generated by the images of the embeddings $PU\to PU^{\otimes n}$, i.~e. by tensors which have almost all components equal to 1. As I suggested in a previous comment, probably more elements may be captured with opens of $\beta(U^n)$ (as opposed to opens of $(\beta U)^n$). Alas, I still did not have opportunity to concentrate on that.

Comment: @porton Still another possibility to consider is the Gleason cover of $(\beta U)^n$ (for Gleason covers, see his ["Projective topological spaces"](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255454110), Theorem 3.2), but so far I do not even see whether it is different from $\beta(U^n)$...

Comment: I started to read that article, but first I didn't understood what is "projective space"?

Comment: In category-theoretic sense. Easiest equivalent property is that it is a retract (by continuous maps) of some $\beta U$ with discrete space $U$.

Answer (score 3):

What follows is another point of view on the answer by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე (which I wouldn't immediately know how to pronounce if I weren't already familiar with the transliteration "Mamuka Jibladze").

**Lemma 1:** If $L$ is a (bounded) distributive lattice, then the poset of join-preserving maps $\phi: L \to \mathbf{2}$ under the pointwise order is a co-frame.

**Proof:** Evidently for such $\phi$ the set $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is an ideal in $L$, so the poset $[L, \mathbf{2}]$ is dual to the poset of ideals under inclusion. It is reasonably well-known that the poset of ideals in a distributive lattice $L$ (or if you prefer, the poset of filters in $L^{op}$, also a distributive lattice) is a frame. QED

**Lemma 2:** If $L_1, \ldots, L_n$ are (finitely many) distributive lattices, then their tensor product $L_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes L_n$ (as commutative monoids under their join operations) is also a distributive lattice.

**Proof:** Here we are viewing distributive lattices as rigs; all that really needs to be checked is that the multiplication on the tensor product rig is indeed the same as conjunction on its underlying poset. But that is an easy calculation using the fact that $\top_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \top_n$ is the top element of the tensor product, together with the idempotence and order-preservation of multiplication. QED

**Proposition:** If $L_1, \ldots, L_n$ are distributive lattices, then the poset of maps $L_1 \times \ldots \times L_n \to \mathbf{2}$ that preserve finite joins in separate arguments is a co-frame.

**Proof:** Because the poset of such maps is identified with the poset of join-preserving maps $L_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes L_n \to \mathbf{2}$, where the domain is a distributive lattice by Lemma 2; this poset is a co-frame by Lemma 1. QED

Applying this proposition to the special case $L_i = P(X_i)$, we have that the poset of $n$-"staroids" for finite $n$ is a co-frame.

However, I do not see that an $n$-"staroid" for infinite cardinals $n$ can be viewed as equivalent to maps out of the infinite tensor product (an appropriate filtered colimit of finite tensor products), because Porton's axiom 3. imposes an extra condition that cannot be deduced from separate join-preservation, as far as I can see. It might however be arguable that condition 3. is not well-motivated.

Comment: The condition 3 is motivated by the fact that "principal staroids" (staroids corresponding to $n$-ary relations in a certain way) are always upper sets. But I am interested in both cases: with and without axiom 3.

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer! I will try to add to mine more details about what does this approach give in the infinite case.